# Comparing values to other values or variables - javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a program that compares two values of emoticons and then returns another one as input. However, when I enter the correct emoticons, nothing happens.
The emoticons look different in code and in real input. windows 10 emoticons.

```js
function output(a) {
    windows.alert(a);
}


emoticon1 = window.prompt("enter emoticon:");
emoticon2 = window.prompt("enter emoticon2");

if (emoticon1 === "☀" ) and (emoticon2 === "☁" ); {
    output("⛅");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the error message you are getting: `Uncaught ReferenceError: windows is not defined`-- this error message explains exactly what is going on: you are trying to reference a variable `windows` that doesn't exist.  At a glance in your `output` function the line `windows.alert(a);` has mistakenly pluralized the `window` object; it should be `window.alert(a);`  _Also_, you have put a semicolon after your `if` condition: `if (emoticon1 === "☀" ) and (emoticon2 === "☁" );`- as such it is _always_ executing the code following in the block. You may want to start using a linter.

Comment: use `&&` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no operator called `and`. [It should be `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).
2. There's no variable called `windows`. [It should be `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), or simply `alert(a)`.
3. Declare your variables properly.
4. Remove that extraneous semi-colon from the if statement.

```js
function output(a) {
  alert(a);
}

const emoticon1 = prompt('enter emoticon:');
const emoticon2 = prompt('enter emoticon2');

if (emoticon1 === '☀' && emoticon2 === '☁') {
  output('⛅');
}
```